# How to visit India after a previous overstay?

Tags: india, overstaying, e-visas

I entered India with a business e-visa of one year with multiple entry, but I spent six months in my own country before I entered India on December 7th, 2019. On March 2020, the COVID pandemic started, so I couldn't go back to my country on July 19th, my return ticket date, so I overstayed until 2022. However, I paid my due penalty before leaving India on May 13th, 2022.

Now, I want to apply for my business visa again to go on my business trip. I was told I have been blacklisted. How can the blacklisting of my passport be cancelled and my visa be granted?

Comment: Who told you you were blacklisted?

Comment: If you are indeed blacklisted, the ban could be indefinite with no likelihood of overturning it https://www.evisasindia.org/overstaying-an-indian-visa/ Were you given any paperwork when you were allowed to exit after paying the fine?

Comment: Even though its not particularly hard to get an Indian visa, India government takes visa rules very seriously and to the letter.

Comment: If the documentation says you are banned indefinitely, it is. You rarely have a recourse.

Comment: Whats the point in a blacklist if it can be easily revoked and an overstayer be granted a new visa?

Answer (score 4):

So if I'm getting this straight, you were supposed to fly out on July 19, 2020, but overstayed by **almost two years** until May 13, 2022.

Now COVID is the kind of *force majeure* event for which many governments would willingly bend the rules a bit, but this also requires that you actively play your part by asking for visa extensions, looking for flights out, etc.  If you did not do any of this, and thus don't have a paper trail documenting that you tried your best to avoid overstaying, it's going to be very difficult to plead for leniency and overturn that blacklisting.